# How to break css column property if content is too long

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to test out having multiple tables with various types of rows displayed on the webpage.

I am then using CSS Columns property to break the content in 4 columns.

My problem when the column finish; it continues the content on the next column. The tables I have can have multiple rows some have 10, some have 5 etc...

What I wanted to do is get page look a bit neater. If you see the picture I have attached below - I have some tables going to the next column.

What is the best practice or how to make this webpage look like a nice grid?

**Here is how it looks**

[image: How it looks now]

**Here is the code:**

```
      <div class="row test">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">Customer Test</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">First</th>
                  <th scope="col">Last</th>
                  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">1</th>
                  <td>Mark</td>
                  <td>Otto</td>
                  <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">2</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">3</th>
                  <td>Larry</td>
                  <td>the Bird</td>
                  <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>



                <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">Customer Test</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">First</th>
                  <th scope="col">Last</th>
                  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">1</th>
                  <td>Mark</td>
                  <td>Otto</td>
                  <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">2</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">3</th>
                  <td>Larry</td>
                  <td>the Bird</td>
                  <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>



                <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">Customer Test</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">First</th>
                  <th scope="col">Last</th>
                  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">1</th>
                  <td>Mark</td>
                  <td>Otto</td>
                  <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">2</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">3</th>
                  <td>Larry</td>
                  <td>the Bird</td>
                  <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>



                <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">Customer Test</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">First</th>
                  <th scope="col">Last</th>
                  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">1</th>
                  <td>Mark</td>
                  <td>Otto</td>
                  <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">2</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">3</th>
                  <td>Larry</td>
                  <td>the Bird</td>
                  <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>


                <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">Customer Test</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">First</th>
                  <th scope="col">Last</th>
                  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">1</th>
                  <td>Mark</td>
                  <td>Otto</td>
                  <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">2</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">3</th>
                  <td>Larry</td>
                  <td>the Bird</td>
                  <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>



                <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">Customer Test</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">First</th>
                  <th scope="col">Last</th>
                  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">1</th>
                  <td>Mark</td>
                  <td>Otto</td>
                  <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">2</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">3</th>
                  <td>Larry</td>
                  <td>the Bird</td>
                  <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>


                <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">Customer Test</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">First</th>
                  <th scope="col">Last</th>
                  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">1</th>
                  <td>Mark</td>
                  <td>Otto</td>
                  <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">2</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                  <th scope="row">2</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">2</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">3</th>
                  <td>Larry</td>
                  <td>the Bird</td>
                  <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
                <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">Customer Test</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">First</th>
                  <th scope="col">Last</th>
                  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">1</th>
                  <td>Mark</td>
                  <td>Otto</td>
                  <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">2</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">3</th>
                  <td>Larry</td>
                  <td>the Bird</td>
                  <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
                   <tr>
                  <th scope="row">3</th>
                  <td>Larry</td>
                  <td>the Bird</td>
                  <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>




    </body>
  </html>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <!-- Bootstrap Stles -->
    <script src="bootstrap-3.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      .navbar{
        background-color: #EB4646;
        border-radius: 0px;
        color: white;
        padding: 0.2%;
      }

      .test {
      -webkit-column-count: 5;
     -moz-column-count: 5;
          column-count: 5;

    </style>
```

**Edit Answer**
[How it looks again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngXba.png)

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. But since you are using bootstrap, why dont you use the bootstrap grid for that? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is table not breaking up in half between the columns. At the moment, half of the table is on the first column and the other half go to next column...I tried the Bootstrap grip but I get soo much space between the table...So I want a nice grid view where if the table is too long for the column; it can go to the next column.

Comment: plz try this to see if that what you mean  .panel.panel-success {
    display: inline-table;
}

Comment: @godfather I tried your suggestion. It creates soo much white space between tables.

Comment: we can fix the space but does that fix the problem of the column content?

Comment: Yes it has fixed the problem. But so much white space between tables. @godfather I have edited my answer..at the bottom I have the second picture how it looks.

Comment: try to increase the column count

Comment: @godfather I increased the column count to different numbers; still same result.

Comment: weird its working for me i increased to 6 and 7

Comment: @godfather. Can you send your code to my email if I give you my email. I tried and not working or any chance you can post code here.

Comment: last question is .test{} closed ? or like the css you posted

Comment: .test is closed {}.

Comment: ok do you have it on github?

Comment: i dont know if this is the problem but do you have the css bootstrap links  in the head?

Comment: sorry for  taking time to solve it

Comment: I have just created a github repo; 
 https://github.com/muhammadikram0192/Demo/blob/master/test.php

Comment: ok ill check it

Comment: ok here your code is working fine and i can change the column from 4 to 5

Comment: I got 5 columns in css property ; but still see 4 columns on the webpage.  But if I remove CSS for .panel.panel-success ; than my code works.

Comment: go to github  we will talk in the issue section if you have time